# SQL - 2 Selects at once. Union doesn't work as expected

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table containing flights to London.
Each connection has it's specific ID. There can be multiple records with different prices for each ID every day. I'm looking for maximum price of the connection for each day + average price of ANY flight to London each day.

This is my query:

```
SELECT entryDate, MAX(totalPrice) AS totalPrice
FROM flights
WHERE connectionID = 'xyz123'
GROUP BY entryDate
UNION ALL 
SELECT entryDate, AVG(totalPrice) AS averagePrice
FROM flights
WHERE destination = 'London'
GROUP BY entryDate
ORDER BY entryDate ASC 
LIMIT 90
```

This is the result:

```
entryDate      totalPrice
2019-05-16     1159.8462
2019-05-16     553.0000
2019-05-17     1164.5736
2019-05-17     553.0000
2019-05-18     1101.8872
2019-05-18     634.0000
2019-05-19     1081.9766
2019-05-19     634.0000
2019-05-20     1119.6250
2019-05-20     634.0000
2019-05-21     1074.5781
2019-05-22     1079.2923
2019-05-23     1060.1641
2019-05-24     1116.1550
```

Note that in last 4 days (21~24) the result from MAX(totalPrice) is not available, because the specific connection 'xyz123' was not in operation.

Anyway, my intention is to get this result:

```
entryDate      totalPrice      averagePrice
2019-05-16     553.0000        1159.8462
2019-05-17     553.0000        1164.5736
2019-05-18     634.0000        1101.8872
2019-05-19     634.0000        1081.9766
2019-05-20     634.0000        1119.6250
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT entryDate,
       MAX(CASE WHEN connectionID = 'xyz123' THEN totalPrice END) AS totalPrice,
       AVG(CASE WHEN destination = 'London' THEN totalPrice END) as averagePrice
FROM flights f
GROUP BY entryDate;
```

If you want only days with *both* values:

```
SELECT entryDate,
       MAX(CASE WHEN connectionID = 'xyz123' THEN totalPrice END) AS totalPrice,
       AVG(CASE WHEN destination = 'London' THEN totalPrice END) as averagePrice
FROM flights f
WHERE connectionID = 'xyz123' OR
      destination = 'London'
GROUP BY entryDate
HAVING SUM( connectionID = 'xyz123' ) > 0 AND
       SUM( destination = 'London' ) > 0;
```

Leave out the `HAVING` clause if you are content with just one value on the date.

Comment: Thank you Gordon! That really helps. The only issue remaining is that it returns also rows where **any** or **both** values are missing. For example:

`entryDate      totalPrice      averagePrice`
`2019-05-23     NULL              1060.1641`